# How to use series. apply() to create conditional pandas series?

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to create a new column in my df using numerical data from another column. I attempted using a for loop and a series of if statements to categorize the numerical data into strings that I want to now use to create the new column. The following data is from the WNBA 2010-2011 dataset about the players.

```
def clean(col):  
    for xp in col:
        if xp < 1:
            print('Rookie')
        elif ((xp >= 1) and (xp <= 3)):
            print('Little experience')
        elif ((xp >= 4) and (xp <= 5)):
            print('Experienced')
        elif ((xp > 5) and (xp < 10)):
            print('Very experienced')
        elif (xp > 10):
            print("Veteran")
```

I tried using series.apply() and series.map() but both of these return a new column called XP as follows

```
XP = df.Experience.apply(clean) 
df['XP'] = XP
```

However, when I checked the dtypes it says that the newly created column is a NONETYPE object. Is this because I am using the print function in the for loop as opposed to manipulating the actual value? If so what should I do to return the string values specified?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: The best answer to your title is that you shouldn't. That `.apply` is a slow loop, in pandas you would choose to use `np.select`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913659/pandas-conditional-creation-of-a-series-dataframe-column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'xp':[0,2,4,6,20,'4']})
```

Put in a string because you had the type error.

```
def clean(str_xp):
     xp = int(str_xp)
     if xp < 1: 
         return('Rookie') 
     elif ((xp >= 1) and (xp <= 3)): 
         return('Little experience') 
     elif ((xp >= 4) and (xp <= 5)): 
         return('Experienced') 
     elif ((xp > 5) and (xp < 10)): 
         return('Very experienced') 
     elif (xp > 10): 
         return ("Veteran") 

df['rank'] = df['xp'].apply(clean)
```

df returns:

```
   xp               rank
0   0             Rookie
1   2  Little experience
2   4        Experienced
3   6   Very experienced
4  20            Veteran
5   4        Experienced
```

Comment: Thank you for you reply. I was wondering why on index number 5 of your output, the xp value is 4 where the string '5' was used  in the initial list? Sorry I am new to python. I'd appreciate some elaboration if you could? Thanks again

Comment: Edited it now, now its like its supposed to be

Answer (score 1):

That's because your function doesn't return anything (so returns None by default). You need to replace those `print` statements with `return`.

Also, you don't need to loop over the column in your function - apply does that for you in a vectorized way. Try this:

```
def clean(xp):  
    if xp < 1:
        return 'Rookie'
    elif ((xp >= 1) and (xp <= 3)):
        return 'Little experience'
    elif ((xp >= 4) and (xp <= 5)):
        return 'Experienced'
    elif ((xp > 5) and (xp < 10)):
        return 'Very experienced')
    elif (xp > 10):
        return "Veteran"

df['XP'] = df.Experience.apply(clean)
```

Bear in mind also that the way your equalities are currently written, your function will return `None` if `xp == 10`.

Comment: Thanks Simon for the reply. I tried what you suggested and it gave me back a type error

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable.

should have mentioned that the df.Experience column is an interfere dtype.

Comment: Restarted the kernel and got this error

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Any ideas?

Comment: Hey Oscar, thay could be because some of your input is a string, maybe my code solves this.